# date formatting according to local pc region

Tags: javascript, date

I am trying to create a JAVASCRIPT code that needs to display the date format according to pc region settings. I need to the following pattern for "April 19, 2013" to be represented as 04/19/2013" or "19/04/2013" or "2013/04/19" whichever the applicable in the region.

Comment: Very well, carry on. Best of luck. Go get 'em. ... Or did you have a *question*?

Answer (score 0):

Below way, a light weight approach, might be helpful: [however, there are many jquery plugins/library available)

1. Save date in db in UTC format (if not in utc format then convert it into utc format)
2. In javascript,
   var localeDate = new Date("{Utc Date from Server}" + " utc") //just append "utc" with date

If you are ASP.NET MVC guy then below snippet might be helpful:

$("#spanTime").text(new Date('@Model.EventDateTimeStr' + " utc").stringFormat("MM/DD/YYYY"));

```
Date.prototype.stringFormat = function (format) {
    var months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
    var monthsFull = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

    var dt = this;
    var h = dt.getHours();
    var d = dt.getDate();
    var M = dt.getMonth() + 1;
    var yyyy = dt.getFullYear();
    var yy = padBefore((yyyy + "").substr(2, 2), 2);
    var m = dt.getMinutes();

    var dd = padBefore(d, 2);
    var MM = padBefore(M, 2);
    var mm = padBefore(m, 2);

    var MMM = months[M - 1];
    var MMMM = monthsFull[M - 1];

    var H = h;
    var HH = padBefore(h, 2);
    var hh = "";
    var tt = "PM";

    if (h >= 12) {
        if (h != 12) {
            h = h - 12;
        }
    } else {
        if (h == 0) h = 12;
        tt = " AM";
    }

    hh = padBefore(h, 2);

    return format
        .replace("hh", hh)
        .replace("h", h)

        .replace("HH", HH)
        .replace("H", H)

        .replace("mm", mm)
        .replace("m", m)




        .replace("dd", dd)
        .replace("d", d)

        .replace("MMMM", MMMM)
        .replace("MMM", MMM)
        .replace("MM", MM)
        /*.replace("M", M)*/

        .replace("yyyy", yyyy)
        .replace("yy", yy)

        .replace("tt", tt);

};
```

Answer (score 0):

You could format the date based on navigator.language

see

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.navigator.language

```
var lang= navigator.browserLanguage || navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;
```